# How to clear text highlights

Tags: javascript

Hi I am highlighting text through window.find and selectRange methods. And I am using below code to remove highlights.. But it does not seems to work..

```
    if (window.getSelection) {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        document.selection.empty();
    }
```

Please let me know mistakes in this code

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/qmR5m/6/) is the fiddle.

Comment: @ben lee no not working in my Chrome browser(Version 15)...

Comment: I don't have an answer. But in my Chrome 15.0.874.121 your jsfiddle is workign. That's all I can say.

Comment: Oh wait, maybe I misunderstood what it was supposed to be doing. Maybe it doesn't work. But it's still not clear to me what "working" would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/qmR5m/7/

What I did was simply strip the body text of spans with the class "Apple-style-span".

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

selection.collapseToEnd(true);

where selection is your selection object.

Comment: that was rather harsh! collapsing a selection will remove the highlight and since you're removing all ranges in your code, I assume you don't care about cursor position either. At the very least lemme know what's wrong with my answer so that I may learn as well.